# An alternative for Thread.Sleep() when using asynchronous servlets?

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, asynchronous

What I'm trying to do is to wait for all requests from users in a specific webpage to come in (they are coming in at **about** the same time), then process them in a servlet, checking which requests send the correct value for some parameter, and output the final result to all the users. I'm using asyncContexts for this, and I am currently using Thread.Sleep(1000) for each user on his request, so that the final result is outputted only when the data is completely collected. However, I've read that Thread.Sleep(1000) is very inefficient to use in web apps, and was wondering if you could suggest some other way of ensuring all the data is collected before the results are outputted. I could provide code if necessary, however, it is a bit messy.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you know about the number of requests that will be there on your Servlet. So in that case you may use a CountDownLatch, Semaphore or any Blocking collection provided in Java 5 concurrency API.